# Refresh map in Activity does not react

Tags: android, android-mapview

I have an activity that extends MapActivity and has two main elements, list view on the left and map on the right. I put a refresh button on the map and tried to :

```
map.setTraffic(true);
map.invalidate();
```

but nothing changed. the map did not refresh. I did searched a bit on google and understood that invalidate() should do the trick. I would like to avoid recreating the entire activity. Please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not even need the `invalidate()`. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/blob/master/Maps/NooYawk) toggles between regular and satellite tiles just by calling `setSatellite()` when you press the `<S>` key in the emulator.

Temporarily switch to `setSatellite()` instead of `setTraffic()`. If that works, then the problem is tied to the traffic tile set, which I have never tried.

Comment: i changed by default to this: map.setTraffic(true) and it didn't changed either.. so the invalidate() is ok. i will post my solution when i find one. thanks for the help, still :)

Comment: @GabrielaRadu: Try running my sample app. If that works, then you can try to determine what you are doing differently. If my app fails, the problem is with your device or emulator, as I run that app on all sorts of devices and emulators, usually a couple of times a month, and I am certain that it works.